# Using two excel date cells to populate a single excel general cell with a specific format.

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to use two excel mm/dd/yyyy cells to populate an excel general cell with a mm/dd/yyyy.mm/dd/yyyy format for use with another software application. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) function to combine text.

If the cells containing the dates are formatted as a date, then you will need to convert the date to text, using the [`TEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c?ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU) in order to get it to appear the way you want.

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),".",TEXT(B1,"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

[image]

If the cells are formatted as text, you can simplify the formula to just the `CONCATENATE` function.

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,".",B1)
```

In this example, I placed the dates to be combined in `A1` and `B1`. The formula is in `D1`. You simple need to change the reference in the formula to the cells your data is in.

Comment: FYI: `=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1)` is equivalent to `=A1 & B1 & C1` - the same if e.g. B1 is replaced by `TEXT(...)`